# Numerical evidence of law of iterated logarithm (random walk)

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, random-walk, simulation

The [law of iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm) states that for a random walk $$S_n = X_1 + X_2 + ... X_n$$ with $X_i$ independent random variables such that $P(X_i = 1) = P(X_i = -1) = 1/2$, we have

$$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n / \sqrt{2 n \log \log n} = 1, \qquad \rm{a.s.}$$

---

Here is Python code to test it:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 10*1000*1000
B = 2 * np.random.binomial(1, 0.5, N) - 1       # N independent +1/-1 each of them with probability 1/2
B = np.cumsum(B)                                # random walk
plt.plot(B)
plt.show()

C = B / np.sqrt(2 * np.arange(N) * np.log(np.log(np.arange(N))))
M = np.maximum.accumulate(C[::-1])[::-1]        # limsup, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35149843/running-max-limsup-in-numpy-what-optimization
plt.plot(M)
plt.show()
```

---

## Question:

**I have done it *lots of times*, but the ratio is nearly always decreasing to 0, instead of having a limit 1.**

**Where is the problem?**

Here's the kind of plot I have most often for the ratio (which should approach $1$):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is that the number of attempts that can be used in a numerical simulation $n$ is finite.

Notice this: if $Y_n=\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{2n\log\log n}}$, by properties of random walk we know $\mathbb{E}[Y_n]=\frac{\mathbb{E}[S_n]}{\sqrt{2n\log\log n}}=0$ and 
$$
Var[Y_n]=\frac{Var[S_n]}{2n\log\log n}=\frac{n}{2n\log\log n}=\frac{1}{2\log\log n}\to 0
$$
which implies $Y_n$ converges to 0 in distribution (we can prove it using [Chebyshev's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality)). 
In particular, if we define $Y_{k,n}=\max_{k\leq \ell \leq n}Y_\ell$ (which is the variable you are using in your code, instead of the variable $Z_k=\sup_{\ell \geq k}Y_{\ell}$ which is the variable one *should* use), then  "$Y_{k,n}\searrow_{k\to n} Y_n$", which in turn converges to 0. So, in the large majority of cases, in your simulations $Y_{k,n}$ should converge to 0.

Comment: @Basj "in the large majority of cases, in your simulations Yk,n should converge to 0." Indeed, for samples of length $10^n$, one obtains a limit at least $\alpha$ with probability roughly $10^{-n\alpha^2}$. For example, to observe a limit at least $.9$ in samples of length $10^7$ requires to repeat the simulation a number of times of the order of $5\cdot10^5$.

Comment: Many thanks @NateRiver. You're right: without noticing it, I was indeed working with $max_{k \leq \ell \leq n} Y_\ell  \rightarrow_{k \rightarrow n} Y_n$ and *not* with $sup_{k \leq \ell} Y_\ell$. That clearly explains why it converges to $0$. Thanks for that. Now do you have an idea how I could do a numerical simulation showing that $(2 n \log \log n)^{1/2}$ is the right magnitude order, and that $\sqrt{n} (\log \log n)^{2/3}$ is not the right order of magnitude? Because of the double log (very small values), it's difficult to see this in a simulation.

Comment: @Did Could I get something by considering $Y_{n/2, n} = \max_{n/2 \leq \ell \leq n} Y_\ell$ ?

Comment: Did and @NateRiver, maybe you would have an idea for this really linked question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637989/test-a-law-of-iterated-logarithm-like-result-with-numerical-simulation ?

Comment: @Basj one quick and dirty idea to avoid the problem of your simulations going almost certainly to 0, is to consider the same variables $Y_{k,n}$, but only plot them for $k\in \{1,...,n/2\}$. That said, I ran some simulations with this trick and while they didn't converge to 0 as $k\to n/2$, they didn't converge to 1, either. I'm kind of afraid that the only way to get results somewhat closer to 1 is to use way larger values of $n$ than the ones being used, which sadly results in memory problems : (.

Comment: btw maybe [this topic](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/230031/how-to-check-numerically-iterated-logarithm-law-how-to-choose-cutoff-lim-n-su) might soon have some answers which could be useful to you.